# Chaining Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create code that will filter entity framework queries that is reusable and readable. The code I have below works except when I want to join two filters, as attempted in the commented out sections. Is anyone able to give direction and guidance on how to make this work?

Below is the compile time error message that vs2012 displays when the line

```
//IList<Department> departments3 = context.Set<Department>().Where(isHumanResourcesDepartment || isAccountsDepartment).ToList(); is uncommented
```

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Func < EfGenericRepositoryPoc.DataModel.Department,bool >' and
>   'System.Func < EfGenericRepositoryPoc.DataModel.Department,bool >'

```
    private static void TestCodeReadability2()
    {

        EmployeeDepartmentsConnection context = new EmployeeDepartmentsConnection();

        IList<Department> departments = context.Set<Department>().Where(isAccountsDepartment).ToList();
        IList<Department> departments2 = context.Set<Department>().Where(isHumanResourcesDepartment).ToList();

        //IList<Department> departments3 = context.Set<Department>().Where(isHumanResourcesDepartment || isAccountsDepartment).ToList();

    }


    private static Func<Department, bool> isAccountsDepartment = d=>d.Name.ToLower().Contains("accounts");
    private static Func<Department, bool> isHumanResourcesDepartment = d=>d.Name.ToLower().Contains("human resources");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, by using Func you are forcing EF to pull all the data from the database and then filter locally, rather than filtering on the database. If you want to filter on the database, wrap the Func in an Expression by changing the static method declarations to

```
Expression<Func<Department, bool>>
```

Comment: He does need to do that, but that alone isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

In order for EF to be able to translate those queries into SQL and perform the work on the database side of things you need to pass in `Expression` objects, not delegates.  To create expressions instead of delegates is pretty darn trivial:

```
private static Expression<Func<Department, bool>> isAccountsDepartment = 
    d => d.Name.ToLower().Contains("accounts");
private static Expression<Func<Department, bool>> isHumanResourcesDepartment = 
    d => d.Name.ToLower().Contains("human resources");
```

Next, to get the set of items where either is true you can use `Union` to get all items in either of two queries.  To make sure that this work is done on the database and not in memory we'll need to remove the `ToList` calls from your inner queries to prevent them from being loaded into memory:

```
private static void TestCodeReadability2()
{
    EmployeeDepartmentsConnection context = new EmployeeDepartmentsConnection();

    var accountsDepartments = context.Set<Department>().Where(isAccountsDepartment);
    var hrDepartments= context.Set<Department>().Where(isHumanResourcesDepartment);

    var combined = accountsDepartments.Union(HRDepartments);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the best way is that at the end of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) article? IMO, this way is better option.

Comment: Also, you must not use `Intersect`, but `Union`. Ain't I right?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev That approach can certainly work; he doesn't need it to accomplish what he described here.  Being able to `And` or `Or` arbitrary expressions is of course more powerful, it just comes at the cost of greater complexity.

Comment: Farhad the article you mentioned is exactly what I was looking for.